# Impossible to add a footer to a ScrollView - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-studio, android-scrollview

I'm currently working on a mobile app and I have a problem when I try to put a footer under a `ScrollView`.

Here is my code:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottomcontent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/border">
            //the footer is added dynamically
    </RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/contentcontainer">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollcontentcontainer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            //the content is added dynamically from a layout template
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The content of the `ScrollView` is a set of relative layout with some buttons and textviews inside. It's based on a layout I'm inflating several times.

The footer is just a LinearLayout with some buttons in it as well.

The thing is I tried all the different solutions I found on Internet and none of them were working. In my case the footer is stuck under the content of the ScrollView, not under the ScrollView itsel so I have to scroll down until the content is over to reach my footer. But the footer is supposed to remain on the bottom of the screen...

I tried those solutions as well, nothing was working:

- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrollable-content-layout-example.html
  (when I try this I have a footer on the top of the screen and nothing else...)
- http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/android-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrollable-content-layout-example
  and some others (not working as well!)

I also tried all the possible things like using gravity, weight, fillViewPort, align to the bottom... But impossible to have the expected result.
The minimum API is set to 14, I use Android Studio.

##### edit1:

border drawable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />

            <solid android:color="#3b010101" />

            <padding android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if that solves the issue?

Comment: add `android:layout_above="@id/bottomcontent"` to your `ScrollView`

Comment: @JaredRummler Done, still not working (footer stuck on top)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, I also had troubles with adding `ScrollView` inside a `RelaveLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border">
        <!---add something there eg:-->

      <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Test"/>

     </RelativeLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomcontent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentcontainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollcontentcontainer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image].

I found the following in [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). This is causing the problem for sure

> Note: In platform version 17 and lower, RelativeLayout was affected by
>   a measurement bug that could cause child views to be measured with
>   incorrect MeasureSpec values. (See MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec for
>   more details.) This was triggered when a RelativeLayout container was
>   placed in a scrolling container, such as a ScrollView or
>   HorizontalScrollView. If a custom view not equipped to properly
>   measure with the MeasureSpec mode UNSPECIFIED was placed in a
>   RelativeLayout, this would silently work anyway as RelativeLayout
>   would pass a very large AT_MOST MeasureSpec instead.
>
> This behavior has been preserved for apps that set
>   android:targetSdkVersion="17" or older in their manifest's uses-sdk
>   tag for compatibility. Apps targeting SDK version 18 or newer will
>   receive the correct behavior

Comment: Sadly I still have my footer on the top of the screen without any other content...

Comment: @Virthuss This is working on my IDE fine, do you get any errors?. Can you add the boarder drawable?

Comment: No error at all... Forgive my poor english but what do you mean by boarder drawable?

Comment: Can you add this part, `android:background="@drawable/border"`

Comment: Can you directly copy my answer xml (whole thing) in to your xml. Just to check? Because, I can not recreate this issue

Comment: @Virthuss This is getting weird. Did you replace your xml with mine or just copy the button only, Because I have to be sure, if not I will try to install v14 and see if I can replicate the issue.

Comment: I copy and paste your code. The thing is as said in the main post, some others solutions I found on internet are working for others users but not in my project ( always the footer stuck on top). It does the same thing with your solution. Adding or removing the content of he layouts doesn't change anything ( I tried to remove the content I'm working on but it doesn't change the footer position).

Comment: @Virthuss can you by any chance min version 17. Then it should work, otherwise you will have to find a work around. I will look for it too.